# Laravel docker image "Could not open input file: /var/www/html/artisan"

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I'm attempting to build and run a Laravel docker image which was originally generated via Laravel sail. When using `docker-compose up`, it correctly runs and I am able to access the site. Running `docker build docker/7.4/ -t <tagname>` followed by `docker run <tagname>` results in the following error logs however:

[image: Example error log, showing "Could not open input file: /var/www/html/artisan"]

I have tracked this error down to my supervisord.conf file, where it is trying to call `/var/www/html/artisan serve`, but is seemingly unable to resolve it.

**supervisord.conf:**

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Here is also the Dockerfile I'm using, as well as the start-container script it runs

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gosu curl zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2

RUN apt-get install -y gnupg ca-certificates

RUN mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php7.4-cli php7.4-dev \
       php7.4-pgsql php7.4-sqlite3 php7.4-gd \
       php7.4-curl php7.4-memcached \
       php7.4-imap php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring \
       php7.4-xml php7.4-zip php7.4-bcmath php7.4-soap \
       php7.4-intl php7.4-readline php7.4-pcov \
       php7.4-msgpack php7.4-igbinary php7.4-ldap \
       php7.4-redis \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php7.4

# RUN groupadd --force -g www-data sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g www-data -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

**start-container:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -z "$WWWUSER" ]; then
    usermod -u $WWWUSER sail
fi

if [ ! -d /.composer ]; then
    mkdir /.composer
fi

chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    exec gosu $WWWUSER "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
fi
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/7.4
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: 'www-data'
        container_name: laravel
        image: sail-7.4/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: 'sail'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        container_name: 'mysql'
        restart: 'unless-stopped'
        tty: 'true'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
            SERVICE_TAGS: 'dev'
            SERVICE_NAME: 'mysql'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

I am fairly new to using docker, so the process is somewhat confusing to me. Any help on where to look for this or how to debug it would be greatly appreciated - as well as an explanation as to why it's unable to resolve the php artisan command in supervisord.conf

Comment: Add your `docker-compose.yml` as well to the question

Comment: I've added it now under the start-container script

Comment: You can see that you are adding it via `volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'` in your `docker-compose` and this is missing in your `docker run`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at your `Dockerfile`, you don't have a copy statement which copies the your source code to the container. And in your docker compose you would would be sharing that code using volumes. Hence your code works fine in `docker-compose up`. But in case of `docker run <image>` that volume is not shared and hence the error

Comment: Funny enough, that is the official Dockerfile that comes with Laravel.

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer? What would that copy statement look like? I couldn't make it work. I'm quite new to Sail, and I'm struggling to understand.

Answer (score 1):

simply add `COPY . /var/www/html` above `COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container`